# Plants have reclaimed Earth, women are the dominant sex

Tags: story-identification, books, post-apocalyptic

I read a book in the 1970s that was on Earth and plants had reclaimed the land. It had creeper like plants that had reached the moon, oaks trapped its victims using cages so it could live off the waste of the creature before it died. A fungus would drop from trees onto peoples heads which took them over or enhanced there thinking as in the case of the heroes.

The only other part of the story that I remember was that the women were the dominant sex and would express their dominance by urinating on the ground and the heroes/heroines in the book climbed the creepers to the moon.

Does it ring a bell with anyone? I would like to find a copy if possible.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It must have been difficult to decipher as upon reading it back I noticed spelling and grammar mistakes that would make my english teacher very angry indeed!
I did not expect to get an answer so I am very grateful and yes this looks like the book or at least one of the 5 short stories that make up the book, will almost certainly be the book that I read. I have downloaded it for kindle and am looking forward to reliving my childhood by reading it. Thank you once again. Andrew

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, you can [accept](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) it by clicking on the check mark next to it.

Comment: Hi Andrew, it looks like you've lost access to the account you used to answer the question and opened a new account to post this thank-you note. You can merge your two accounts by following the instructions [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts), at which point you'll be able to leave your thank-you note as a *comment* on ImaginaryEvents's answer, as well as accept that answer as correct using the green checkmark.

Answer (score 11):

This is [Hothouse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hothouse_%28novel%29) by Brian Aldiss, published in 1962.

[image]

[Brian Aldiss describes it](http://brianaldiss.co.uk/writing/novels/novels-h-l/hothouse/):

> The true successor to Non-Stop, it appeared originally as a series of
>   short stories in The Magazine of Fantasy & Science Fiction. It tells
>   the story of how Gren and Yattmur lived to see the near-end of Earth,
>   when the sun is going nova and Earth presents one face to it. Gren and
>   the parasitic morel travel from brilliance into twilight. The terrors
>   are relieved by the comedy of the tummy belly men.

Comment: Also published as "The Long Afternoon of Earth" :). I was so confused by your title of the book and started to write a new answer, until I read your description. The names were too familiar. A really great, but also disturbing kind of scifi.

Comment: This has now been confirmed by the OP: see 2nd comment on the question (the "thank you" answer below was moved to a comment in the wrong place).